# Seperate edit forms for different role user

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have created two edit forms editform1 and editform2 and now I want to open editform1 for the site owner user (Role) and want to open editform2 for site members (Role) let me know How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In SPD you can restrict a form to a user-role and add a link for it to the ribbon.  In this way the Site Owner would have to specifically click that link but it would not be available for other users.

Comment: But i want to open editform on list item click based on roles.

Comment: Yep I understand.  This suggestion was a quick compromise.  I think you would have to resort to a code solution and intercept the click event.  You could achieve another workaround with XSLT and run a function ONCLICK but that would only be for the specific view and not take into account the ribbon links.